# Generating a simple histogram from list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking an introductory level Python course. In one of my problems, I am supposed to make a function called *def render_histogram*. In this function, I am supposed to take a list of values and when I print the function for some list, I should get out a histogram composed of columns of "*" with a height equal to the number in the list.

[image: Super simple histogram].

The histogram in the picture corresponds to the list `[5, 4, 2, 7, 0, 3, 10]`. This is my code so far:

```
def render_histogram(values):
    st = ""
    rows = []
    for value in values:
        rows.append("*" * value)
    rowrow = (list(map(list,rows)))
    st += "\n".join(rowrow[0])
    return st
print(render_histogram([5, 4, 2, 7, 0, 3, 10]))
```

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Comment: Could you try to implement matplotlib's, seaborn's or another visualisation library's histogram yourself and if you fail come back with your code? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: First time on here, still learning the how to's!

Comment: @PhW welcome to StackOverflow, when composing question or answer, you should take a look at the preview (right below the writing field) to see if your question/answer is displayed correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```py
def render_histogram(values):
    for i in range(max(values), 0, -1):
        print("".join("*" if val >= i else " " for val in values))
```

edit:
If you need the function to return a string:

```py
def render_histogram(values):
    rows = []
    for i in range(max(values), 0, -1):
        rows.append("".join("*" if val >= i else " " for val in values))
    return "\n".join(rows)
```

or in a single, ugly line:

```py
def render_histogram(values):
    return "\n".join("".join("*" if val >= i else " " for val in values) for i in range(max(values), 0, -1))
```

Comment: This works like a charm, however, I need to print the function and not use the function to print the histogram.

Comment: Added a version that returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

This approach creates another list `height` which determines when the loop should start printing `*` based on the value of the element as compared to the maximum value. For the list `[5, 4, 2, 7, 0, 3, 10]`, the output is as given below.

```
def render_histogram(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    height = [0]*n
    maxval = max(lst)
    for i in range(n):
        height[i] = maxval-lst[i]
    
    for i in range(maxval):
        for j in range(n):
            if (i >= height[j]):
                print("*", end = " ")
            else:
                print(" ", end = " ")
        print("\n")
```

**Output**

```
            * 

            *

            *

      *     *

      *     *

*     *     *

* *   *     *

* *   *   * *

* * * *   * *

* * * *   * *
```

Answer (score 0):

The render_histogram function in this code will return the 'chart' as a string that can then be printed out.

```py
def render_histogram(vals):
  height = max(vals)
  chart = []
  for h in range(height, 0, -1):
    row = []
    row = ['*' if val>=h else ' ' for val in vals]
    chart.append(''.join(row))
  return '\n'.join(chart)

print(render_histogram([5, 4, 2, 7, 0, 3, 10]))
```

```
      *
      *
      *
   *  *
   *  *
*  *  *
** *  *
** * **
**** **
**** **
```